# Flutter Get.changeTheme() does not change the app theme (misuse?)

Tags: flutter, dart, get, themes

[Here](https://pub.dev/packages/get#change-theme) described the simplest/lasiest way to change a color theme of the app. It states:

> Please do not use any higher level widget than `GetMaterialApp` in order to update it.

It appears my understanding of how to use the `Get` package is not correct.
Tried 2 variants of the code (with or without the commented out line) - the theme does not change.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      title: 'ThemeDemo',
      // UPDATE: Added 2 lines
      theme: ThemeData.light(),
      darkTheme: ThemeData.dark(),
      themeMode: Get.isDarkMode ? ThemeMode.light : ThemeMode.dark,
      home: const MyHomePage(
        title: 'Theme Demo',
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
        actions: <Widget>[
          PopupMenuButton<String>(
            onSelected: handleClick,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
              return {'Logout', 'Theme'}.map((String choice) {
                return PopupMenuItem<String>(
                  value: choice,
                  child: Text(choice),
                );
              }).toList();
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void handleClick(String value) {
    switch (value) {
      case 'Logout':
        break;
      case 'Theme':
        // UPDATE: Uncommented the control
        Get.changeTheme(Get.isDarkMode ? ThemeData.light() : ThemeData.dark());
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Please, help me to understand the problem and how to use `Get` to change the theme.
I am very beginner in Flutter, so any constructive critics is welcome!

Answer (score 0):

you should specify the Theme and darkTheme in GetMaterialApp then the themeMode,
like this:

```
  GetMaterialApp(
    // your other properties
    theme: YourDefaultTHemeHere,
    darkTheme: YourDarkThemeHere,
    themeMode: Get.isDarkMode ? ThemeMode.light : ThemeMode.dark,
    )
```

Comment: Thanks! Updated the code in the question with this advice + uncommended the controlling line `Get.changeTheme(..)`. The app gets dark theme on start and does not change of "Theme" event. It seems something else is missing.